# Trouble setting Jump List icon in C#

Tags: c#, jump-list

I'm trying to set up a Jump List in my C# application using the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar` library. I want to associate a custom icon with a `JumpListLink`, but I'm encountering an issue.

```
JumpList jumpList = JumpList.CreateJumpList();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Temp.ico"), ImageFormat.Icon);
JumpListLink customTask = new JumpListLink(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0], "Image")
{
    Arguments = "Image arg",
    IconReference = new IconReference(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Temp.ico"))
};
```

Error:

```
Reference path in invalid. (Parameter 'refPath')
```

I'm getting an error at the line `IconReference = new IconReference(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Temp.ico"))`.

Comment: Maybe you should store temp path somewhere instead creating the new one?

Comment: What's the differernt?

Comment: I think the problem is with `IconReference`, That it can't read from icon images or so